# Calling Method from Control not Fully Running

Tags: c#, user-controls, methods, telerik, call

(Using Teleriks' RadPageView)

I have a Method inside a usercontrol which creates and populates a "RadPageView".

```
    public void CreateDemoMap()
    {
        RadPageViewPage pTest = new RadPageViewPage();
        pTest.Text = "Live Map (Demo)";
        radPageViewX.Pages.Add(pTest);
        WebMap wMap = new WebMap();
        pTest.Controls.Add(wMap);
        MessageBox.Show("TEST");
    }
```

From the same form but outside of the user control I have a button calling on the Method.

```
    private void radButtonElement4_Click_(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectDashControl PDC = new ProjectDashControl();
        PDC.CreateDemoMap();
    }
```

The method does run (*Textbox Shows "Test"*) But the RadPageView does not generate.

Running the method localy - I get the intended results and it works fine.

```
    public ProjectDashControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateDemoMap();
    }
```

Suggestions? Thank-you in Advance!

Comment: Does `RadPageViewPage` have controls that need to be initialized?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I've never run into this issue in the past.

Comment: Where is CreateDemoMap() called normally? Are you sure it is being called there?

Comment: CreateDemoMap() Is called on the UserControl which has the radPageViewX on it.

Answer (score 0):

Had to move *Variable* ProjectDashControl PDC to Global Scope and Change to Instance.

```
ProjectDashControl PDC = ProjectDashControl.Instance();
```